# How to login to SFTP server using pem file which have password?

Tags: command-line, ftp, sftp

I have given below details of an SFTP server to login.

ipaddress, username, password, port(8800), password protected ppk file.

I tried the following command to login to server but unable to connect.(I expected giving password to the key after executing the command. And also I have password for both username and key).

```
sftp -i key.pem username@ipaddress -P8800
```

Error message

```
ssh: connect to host xx.xx.xx.xxx port 22: Connection timed out
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

But I am able to telnet to server using below command.

```
telnet ipaddress 8800
```

How is it telnet working but sftp command not working? And how to pass port number in sftp command?

Answer (score 5):

You can see clearly from the error that you have pasted, that SFTP continues to attempt to connect on Port 22. Your '-P' arg is getting ignored.

Order of arguments is fairly important, or at least that 'username@ipaddress' should be at the end of the command is.

```
sftp  -P 8800 -i key.pem username@ipaddress
```

Answer (score 1):

On RedHat/Fedora/CentOS there is no `-i` argument to `sftp` to specify a pem file - this is the syntax:
`sftp -P {port} -oIdentityFile={path to pem} {user}@{host}`